# Why can't I call my function with gestureTapRecogniser

Tags: ios, swift

I have this simple function that when someone taps the screen, the code inside the function executes, I know the code in the function works and I get no error when it is typed.

```
    func reload(gestureRecognizer: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
        let skView = self.view!
        skView.presentScene(scene)
    }
```

I have this if statement, and all the code work except for when I ry to run the function after a certain event has occurred. In the line where I try and call 'reload()' I get the error 'Use of unresolved identifier reload'. Can you please tell me what I've done wrong. Thanks!

```
    if score[0] >= 10 {
        pauseGame()

        let textLabel = SKLabelNode(fontNamed: "Helvetica")
        textLabel.fontSize = 30
        textLabel.fontColor = SKColor.white
        textLabel.position = CGPoint(x:  20, y: 20)
        textLabel.horizontalAlignmentMode = SKLabelHorizontalAlignmentMode.center
        textLabel.text = "HELLO"
        addChild(textLabel)

        reload()

    }
    else if
        score [1] >= 10 {
        pauseGame()
        sleep(5)

        let textLabel = SKLabelNode(fontNamed: "ChalkboardSE-Bold")
        textLabel.fontSize = 30
        textLabel.fontColor = SKColor.white
        textLabel.position = CGPoint(x:  20, y: 20)
        textLabel.horizontalAlignmentMode = SKLabelHorizontalAlignmentMode.center
        textLabel.text = "HELLO"
        addChild(textLabel)

        reload()

    }
```

Comment: You are calling a version of `reload` that doesn't take any parameters. The version of `reload` you defined takes one parameter of type `UITapGestureRecognizer`.

Comment: If you mean change it to reload(gestureRecognizer: UITapGestureRecognizer) I already tried that and  the same error still showed up

Answer (score 1):

Just change

```
reload()
```

to

```
reload(gestureRecognizer: nil)
```

and `reload` method parameter should be `UITapGestureRecognizer?` optional.

```
func reload(gestureRecognizer: UITapGestureRecognizer?) {
        let skView = self.view!
        skView.presentScene(scene)
}
```

**Another short way is**

change action method that declared with `UITapGestureRecognizer`

```
...action: #selector(self.reload())...
```

means remove `(_:)` no need to do anythings more just call `reload()` function.

Comment: Ok thanks, just so I know what I'm actually typing, why does it work with nil and why do I have to make it an optional?

Comment: @mak you can also go with another way too

Comment: Could you show m the code please, I don't really understand, I don't know what you mean by remove (_:)

Comment: self.reload(nil) Is how I'm calling the function, and         func reload(gestureRecognizer: UITapGestureRecognizer?) {
            let skView = self.view!
            skView.presentScene(scene)
        } Is the actual function

Comment: call `reload` like this: `reload(gestureRecognizer: nil)`.

Comment: @MoeAbdul-Hameed yes you are right there is not `_` at start of params @mark plz call like that

Comment: reload(gestureRecogniser: nil)
Still says the same error, I'm still very confused 'Use of unresolved identifier reload'

Comment: how you added TapGesture by code or by storyboard ? if added by code then put here so with tell you where you need to make changes

Comment: func reload(gestureRecognizer: UITapGestureRecognizer?) {
            let skView = self.view!
            skView.presentScene(scene)
        }